# R dcast error / Find irregular IDs in a dataframe

Tags: r, find, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this:

```
ID | value A | value B
1  |   A1    |   F
1  |   A2    |   N
1  |   A3    |   B
1  |   A4    |   S
2  |   A1    |   B
2  |   A2    |   G
2  |   A3    |   N
3  |   A1    |   F
3  |   A2    |   H
3  |   A3    |   J
3  |   A4    |   N
```

So I have 4 rows for one ID each. I am trying to use the dcast() function, but it only works if all IDs have the same number of rows. ID No. 2 would be an error case in this example. Is there any easy way to find all IDs that have more or less than 4 rows?
Or may be is there any way to make the dcast function ignore the error cases?

Originally I am trying to reshape the dataframe to get something like this:

```
ID | A1 | A2 | A3 | A4
 1 | F  | N  | B  | S 
 2 | B  | G  | N  | NA
 3 | F  | H  | J  | N
```

Apparently the dcast() function from the reshape2 package doesn´t work with irregular IDs. It gives me the following erros message: 'Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length' But with a smaller part of my dataset - which doesn´t have those irregular iDs -  it works. Any ideas?
Or may be an idea how to reshape my dataframe without using dcast? Thanks!

I am working on a mac with the following (package-) versions:

```
sessionInfo() 
R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reshape2_1.2.1 plyr_1.7.1    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] stringr_0.6
```

The first column values are all integer, the others character values.

```
sapply(x, class)
         ID      fach01      f01_lp 
  "integer" "character" "character"
```

As for the reproducible example:
I hope this helps (I used my original dataframe), however if I only use the first 500 rows of the dataframe dcast() works perfectly fine, the problem occurs when I try to use the whole dataframe of about 140000 rows.

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L),  A = c("2.LF", 
"1.LF", "3.PF", "4.PF", "3.PF", "1.LF", "2.LF", "3.PF", 
"4.PF", "1.LF", "2.LF", "3.PF", "1.LF", "4.PF", "2.LF", "1.LF", 
"2.LF", "4.PF", "3.PF", "1.LF", "3.PF", "2.LF", "4.PF", "3.PF", 
"4.PF", "1.LF", "2.LF", "4.PF", "2.LF", "3.PF", "1.LF", "1.LF", 
"2.LF", "3.PF", "4.PF"), B = c("Mu/Ku", 
"Fs", "2.AF", "NW", "DE", "2.AF", "MA", "Fs", "2.AF", "NW", 
"NW", "Fs", "2.AF", "bel", "NW", "Fs", "bel", "bel", "NW", "DE", 
"2.AF", "2.AF", "MA", "Fs", "2.AF", "MA", "NW", "DE", "2.AF", 
"MA", "NW", "Mu/Ku", "Fs", "2.AF", "NW")), .Names = c("ID", "A", "B"
), row.names = c("3", "5", "7", "10", "26", "29", "212", "213", 
"32", "35", "38", "39", "43", "44", "45", "48", "53", "56", "57", 
"59", "61", "65", "67", "68", "72", "75", "76", "77", "81", "86", 
"87", "88", "92", "93", "95", "98"), class = "data.frame")
```

In my original dataframe the values A1 -A4 (here called 1.PF - 4.PF) are not in the right order, this is what I want dcast to do (same as above)

```
ID | 1.PF | 2.PF | 3.PF | 4.PF
 1 | F    | NW   | DE   | S 
 2 | bel  | G    | N    | <NA>
 3 | F    | NW   | bel  | N
```

EDIT:

I didn´t solve the dcast() problem, but I found a way to work around it: (reshape() function from the reshape package)

```
df <- reshape(df, idvar='ID', varying = NULL, timevar = 'value A', direction='wide')
```

Comment: Using `dcast` I get exactly what you want -- see below (??)

Comment: So, then why am I not getting what I want. What else could be wrong with my dataframe?

Comment: To go any further we need a *reproducible* example: my example below works for me, and I don't have anything else to work with.  If my example below *doesn't* work for you then it's a difference between software versions (you haven't said what version of R/reshape2 you're using); if it does, but your original data doesn't, then it's something about your data. Take a look at http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ...

Comment: There are several possible ways to read in the dataset you have posted and zero possible ways that it would be printed in that manner from a console session. If I just read in with `sep="|" I get all factor columns with the spaces are retained on either side of the values. Is that your intent?

Comment: Since you've edited your question, I see it's still active. Have you tried following @DWin's advice about updating your copies of `plyr` and `reshape2` ... ? Can you post a *reproducible* example (and specify which versions of the packages you're using)?

Comment: @BenBolker:I  updated my package- and R-version, but it still didn´t work with the whole dataset (about 140.000 rows). I edited the question, see above for the versions I am using. AS for the reproducible example: the one you created is exactly what I am looking for and I must admit that I don´t know how to create another or a better one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table` and `which` would certainly be the answer to the first question:

```
 names(table(dfrm$ID))[which(table(dfrm$ID) <4)]
#[1] "2"
```

As for the second question, maybe you should post the code that is generating the error. At the moment it's not clear what you are trying (and failing) to do.

**EDIT:**

If I convert the factor variables to character variables I can get dcast to return the correct object, although my error is different than yours. I got the error in both reshape 1.1 and reshape 1.2.1 on R 2.14.1 on a Mac.

**EDIT2:** As it turned out the bug was fixed in the newest version of plyr. I get no error with reshape 1.2.1 running with plyr 1.7. You should also update those two packages and restart with a fresh session.

```
require(reshape2)
dfrm <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), value.A = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("   A1    ", 
"   A2    ", "   A3    ", "   A4    "), class = "factor"), value.B = structure(c(2L, 
6L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("   B", "   F", 
"   G", "   H", "   J", "   N", "   S"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"value.A", "value.B"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
dcast(dfrm2, ID ~ value.A)
# Using value.B as value column: use value_var to override.
# Error in names(data) <- array_names(res$labels[[2]]) : 
#  'names' attribute [4] must be the same length as the vector [1]
# I first tried removing the leading and trainly spaces with:
dfrm2 <- data.frame(lapply(dfrm, gsub, patt="^\\s+|\\s+$", rep=""))
# Still got the error. Now try to leave as "character" type.

dfrm2 <- data.frame(lapply(dfrm, gsub, patt="^\\s+|\\s+$", rep=""),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
str(dfrm2)
#-----------------
'data.frame':   11 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ ID     : chr  "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
 $ value.A: chr  "A1" "A2" "A3" "A4" ...
 $ value.B: chr  "F" "N" "B" "S" ...

dcast(dfrm2, ID ~ value.A)
#------------------
Using value.B as value column: use value_var to override.
  ID A1 A2 A3   A4
1  1  F  N  B    S
2  2  B  G  N <NA>
3  3  F  H  J    N
```

Comment: I edited the questions. See above for the error message I am constantly getting.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the research on the package and your help. It seems obvious but for some reason this solution still does not work for me. I am still getting the same error message you did. (With the new package version and rewriting the dataframe as character types like you did in your example.) Also, dcast only works for me if I additionally use 'value_var = value.B', otherwise it just gives me the frequences instead of the actual values in column B. So I am wondering, how did you do it? And why doesn´t it do the same for me?

Comment: You should put an addendum in your question that shows what packages you have loaded. Sometimes mysterious errors arise because of package conflicts. The standard way to do this is to show the results of sessionInfo() .

Comment: The first three lines of @DWin's code work for me (after fixing a small typo: `dfrm2` should be `dfrm` in the third statement), cutting and pasting into a clean R session, with reshape2 1.2.1 and plyr 1.7.1 .

Answer (score 2):

You should mention that `dcast` is from the `reshape2` package (not part of base R). I'm not sure what you're trying to do with it, but this should do what you ask for.

Make up data:

```
id <- rep(1:3,c(4,3,4))
d <- data.frame(id)
d <- ddply(d,.(id),
           function(x) {
             transform(x,A=paste("A",seq(nrow(x)),sep=""),
                       B=sample(LETTERS,nrow(x),replace=TRUE))
           })
```

Identify 'bad' groups:

```
idtab <- table(d$id)
d2 <- d[!id %in% names(idtab)[idtab<4],]
```

While I can do this, if I try to use the full data set, `dcast` does the "right" thing (i.e. what I would have hoped for and what it sounds like you want), and fills in the missing values with an `NA`; I didn't get an error (I'm using `reshape2` v 0.8.4 under a development version of R).

```
library(reshape2)
```

With the sanitized data:

```
dcast(d2,id~A)
# Using B as value column: use value.var to override.
#   id A1 A2 A3 A4
# 1  1  B  X  P  E
# 2  3  F  Q  H  B
```

With the original data:

```
dcast(d,id~A)
# Using B as value column: use value.var to override.
#   id A1 A2 A3   A4
# 1  1  B  X  P    E
# 2  2  I  N  H <NA>
# 3  3  F  Q  H    B
```

Comment: when I try the dcast() function is gives me the following error message: 'Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length' but when I try it just on a small part of my dataset (where no irregular rows are) it works. So I figured the irregular rows are the problem. Or could it be anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Try `tapply`.  (If the third column is already `character`, as opposed to `factor`, then `as.character` can be omitted):

```
tapply(as.character(DF[,3]), DF[-3], c)
```